# Generic way of constructing objects

Tags: c#, generics

I have two classes:

```cs
class DoorRequest : IRequest
{
   string message;
}

class WindowRequest : IRequest
{
  string message;
}
```

They do not inherit from each other, but implement a common interface.
I would like to have a generic way for creation of instances of these classes. Something semantically equivalent to:

```cs
public static T MakeOpenRequest<T>() where T : IRequest
{
  // If T is DoorRequest return new DoorRequest{message="please open the door"}
  // If T is WindowRequest return new WindowRequest{message="please open the window"}
}
```

What is important to me is that the result of the function is `T`, not `IRequest`. I can extend functionalities of `DoorRequest` and `WindowRequest` to provide actual implementations. The real-life logic of `MakeOpenRequest` can be imagined to be much more complex, so writing a plain factory would lead to massive code duplication. The only thing this method cares about is that it is supposed to create instances of some types in a named way, that is to be defined for each class separately.

I doubt regular constructors would help here, because there is hardly any genericity to be taken advantage of. Constructing methods must be static, so I can't really count on polymorphism on them.

What's the neatest way to tackle this task? Reflection would be cheating, but if there is no other way then it's fine.

Comment: You can do things with `Dictionary<Type, Func<IRequest>>` collections to essentially encapsulate construction. How these `Func`s come into being is another matter; you could initialize these statically or use reflection.

Comment: Why do you not have a method on the interface such as `SetOpenMessage()`? Then you could just require that the `T` has a parameterless constructor, call that method, and then return the object.

Comment: What if I wrote my own request `class FooRequest: IRequest { int foo; }`? What would `MakeOpenRequest<FooRequest>()` do?

Comment: In reality I actually do need a single string to create these messages. Each message is a quite big autogenerated partial class that exposes a special constructor taking a string and setting some internal, private variables. Thus, `SetOpenMessage` doesn't seem like a solution.

Comment: As for the `FooRequest` made from int, it doesn't really matter in my case because I assume there is always an option to create "open request messages" from strings, regardless of the internals.

Comment: So then a `Func<string, IRequest>` would adequately encapsulate construction of these types. Call and cast to `T`. A simple dictionary could do it (`{ typeof(DoorRequest), s => new DoorRequest(s) }`), or indeed reflection to find the single-argument public constructor that takes a `string` if it's really the same thing over and over.

Comment: A lot of the comments/answers here are glossing over the fact that OP wants to set a different value (message) based on the specific type being used. This significantly complicates (and IMO defeats) the intention of using generics to solve this problem.

Comment: I am totally ready for an answer that it's something one just doesn't do in C#. My thinking is under high influence of FP and I am not very used to OOP. 

What I had in mind was something like (welcome Haskell) `class IRequest a where makeOpen :: a` with instances `instance IRequest DoorReq where makeOpen = DoorReq "pls open door"`, so I can write stuff of kind 

`tryOpenReq :: IRequest m => IO (Maybe m)`

`tryOpenReq = isOpen >>= \open -> if open then return Nothing else return (Just makeOpen)`

Comment: As soon as you type `if (T is something) {}` you should stop because you're doing it wrong.

Comment: To take advantage of [Polymorphism](https://www.google.com/search?q=polymorphism), you should be able to program against `IRequest`. E.g., instead of calling `OpenDoor()` on a DoorRequest and `OpenWindow()` on a WindowRequest, you should call `Open()` (or even `Activate()` to be more generic) on a `IRequest` (otherwise you will need to do the `if (T is something)` thing pointed out by @BanksySan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You should really consider a solution that does not rely on generics; since your intended code does not behave the same way for all concretions of that generic type. That is the first big red flag that generics are not the right approach.

---

The only way to instantiate a generic type is if the chosen type has a parameterless constructor. This also requires you to specify this as a generic type constraint.

Since you want your code to work agnostically of all possible types, your method cannot actually decide the correct message to be used (as this would require knowing the specific type, which leads to OCP violations). Therefore, the message should be defined in the concrete `IRequest` implementation itself.

However, this leaves your method itself with nothing to do other than call the constructor:

```
interface IRequest { }

class DoorRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Message { get; }

    public DoorRequest()
    {
        Message = "Please open the door";
    }
}

class WindowRequest : IRequest
{
    public string Message { get; }

    public WindowRequest()
    {
        Message = "Please open the window";
    }
}

static class Foo
{
    public static T MakeOpenRequest<T>() where T : IRequest, new()
    {
        var obj = new T();

        return obj;
    }
}
```

---

If you need the message to be decided in the `MakeOpenRequest` function and not in the `IRequest` implementation itself, and the message is specific to the type `T` being used, then the only possible solution is for `MakeOpenRequest` to change its behavior based on the specific type, which is not a good use case for generics. It is indicative of a bad design and is an OCP violation.

In this case, you should look for an alternative approach, because generics are not the way to go. Most likely, you'd be better off opting for specific methods (`MakeDoorRequest`, `MakeWindowRequest`), since it doesn't really matter to the consumer if they have to call `MakeOpenRequest<WindowRequest>` or `MakeWindowRequest`, since both require the same knowledge of concrete types.

You mention in your question that things might get much more complex. At this point, your should consider the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) as opposed to trying to do the same with generics.

Comment: How would it work if I have `MakeCloseRequest` and other similar too?

Comment: @Radrow I cannot answer that based on the name alone, but the advice is presumably identical.

Comment: What I meant is that you used parameterless constructor to create an opening request. Therefore, you can't use it for any other one.

Comment: @radrow: You should really consider a solution that does not rely on generics; since your intended code _does not behave the same way_ for all concretions of that generic type. That is the first big red flag that generics are not the right approach.

Comment: Got it. You could add your last comment to the answer, as it is the very point in which I was wrong in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be solvable using the upcoming in C# 11 [static abstract members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#static-abstract-members-in-interfaces):

```
interface IRequest<T> where T : IRequest<T> {
  static abstract T MakeOpenRequest<T>();
}

class DoorRequest : IRequest<DoorRequest>
{
  string message;

  WindowRequest MakeOpenRequest() => new WindowRequest(){message = "open door"}
}

class WindowRequest : IRequest<WindowRequest>
{
  string message;

  WindowRequest MakeOpenRequest() => new WindowRequest(){message = "open window"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're thinking about it the wrong way around.  You want a factory that creates `IRequest` objects, dependent on some argument passed.

Example:

```
enum RequestTypes {
   DoorRequest,
   WindowRequest
}

class RequestFactory {
    public IRequest Create(RequestType requestType) {
        switch(requestType) {
            case RequestType.DoorRequest:
                return new DoorRequest();
            case RequestType.WindowRequest:
                return new WindowRequest();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("requestType");
        }
    }
}
```

No generics needed, just good olde fashioned polymorphism.

This assumes that `IRequest` is correct.  It should be:

```
interface IRequest {
    string message;
}
```

You *never* need to cast it up to an explicit `DoorRequest`, you just work with the returned `IRequest`.

Comment: This makes me unable to write `DoorRequest r = Create(...)` (modulo dynamic casts)

Comment: Yes, because that would be wrong.  Do you need an `DoorRequest` or an `IRequest` to a `DoorRequest`?  I strongly suspect it's the latter.

Comment: `string message` should be in `IRequest`.

Comment: I need `DoorRequest` (or `WindowRequest`) specifically, as I depend on that in the places where the creating code is called.

Comment: Then that code is wrong.  That code should be accepting `IRequest`, not the concrete types.